# Georeferenced Image Overlay and export to new image

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, saga, overlay, matlab

I have two Geotiffs (one satellite image, one clipped image). I want to put the clipped image over the satellite image, because it shows flow velocity from this shown glacier (see image below). I tried qgis, Saga and Matlab with no problems to load and visualize that on screen. But I'm not able to export this overlay to a new geotiff. I've tried Raster Merge in qgis with layer stacking, but I can't visualize like same before. I need geotiff to put more information on it.

Does anyone have an idea for how can I resolve that?

[image: Overlay Screenshot]

Comment: A couple of questions..."but I can't visualize like same before. "  at what point/what software were you able to have this working before?  Also, what is the projection of each of these files?

Comment: Sorry, I mean with "like same before" this visualisation that you can see on screenshot, sorry my english is not the best. When I use Layerstack I'cant assign color ramp to the overlayed part of the image. The screenshot is made in qgis. Both of the images are in UTM